# Regex to validate final of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

If you want to validate a text from your site, always save the ends with .m3u8.

I had used my template the following validation:

validates: url, format: {with: / 'here insert regex' /,
message: "Allow only .m3u8 files"}

How could be the regex of my validation to check if the end of my url has .m3u8?

Comment: `/\.m3u8$/` this will be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using below regexp.

```
test_url = 'test_url.m3u8'
regexp = /([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-\(\):])+(.m3u8)$/i
if !regexp.test(test_url)
  puts 'MATCHED'
else
  puts 'NOT MATCHED'
```